# Int to Byte and then back to Int does not return the same value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have to send an array of integer value over the network. They can only be sent as a byte array `byte[]`.

But the problem is that when that byte that is received by the other device - when converted back to int does not give the same value?

Below code and its output is the problem that I am facing

```
int x = GetUniqueID();
Debug.Log("Int value is: " + x.ToString());
byte b = (byte)x;
Debug.Log("Converted to byte is: " + b.ToString());
int y = (int)b;
Debug.Log("Converted back to int is: " + y.ToString());

private int GetUniqueID()
    {
        int x;
        x = Random.Range(0, 1000);

        return x;
    }
```

And here is the console output of the above code (run twice):

[image]

Why is the original value not returned after the int is converted to byte?

Comment: A byte is a number between 0 and 255.  You are truncating an integer 344 which is larger than 255 which is giving different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting an `int`, which is 32 bits or 4 bytes, into a `byte` which is a single byte. This causes your value to be truncated, which is why you are seeing it reduce from 344 to 88 in your example.

Instead try using the [BitConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter?view=net-6.0) class to convert an `int` into a `byte[]`

```
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(x)
```

Comment: Thank you. That explains why I am having this problem. The code above is for a multiplayer messaging system and I need to transfer over a byte array of exactly 4 elements. One of the elements is this ``int``. Using your suggested ``BitConverter`` will take me above the 4 elements per byte array as this single int will be an array in itself. Is there any way to reliably convert an int or even float to a single byte and then back to that value? Thanks

Comment: No you will not be able to store an `int`, which is an alias for `System.Int32`, a 4 byte number, into a single element of a `byte[]` which is a `byte`, or 1 byte. Do you need to use a full 32 bit integer in the first place, can you get away with using a byte which allows values from 0 - 255?

Comment: Hmmm.. I may have to but its not ideal, as it represents the unique number of units on the battleground. This limits me to 255 only. I can increase the number of elements per byte array in the messaging system if I know how many more elements the ``BitConverter`` will add. Can you please also mention how to convert the byte array from BitConverter back to my int value? Thank you

Comment: I figured it out. I can convert the byte array back to my ``Int32`` using ``BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0);`` where b is the byte array and the other will always be 0 I guess as its the staring index of that array. :)